# Can't get Python 3.2.5 and cx_Oracle to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-oracle

I need to connect to Oracle database using python. So, I did the following:

1. I downloaded instantclient_11_2 basic and sdk from Oracle site.
2. Put the files on /opt/ora/instantclient
3. export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/ora/instantclient
4. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME
5. cd $ORACLE_HOME && ln -s libclntsh.so.11.1 libclntsh.so
6. Downloaded and installed cx_Oracle-5.1.1-11g-py32-1.x86_64.rpm

But when I tried to run `import cx_Oracle` I got this error:

```
ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle
```

According to [cx_Oracle site](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/README.txt) I need to Place the file cx_Oracle.pyd or cx_Oracle.so anywhere on your Python path. But I can't find those files after installing cx_Oracle-5.1.1-11g-py32-1.x86_64.rpm..

By the way, I also tried to install using zipped version but I got a lot error upon building like `error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Is there anything I did wrong?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Got it solved guys. I upgraded my python to latest, used cx_Oracle for python33, and instantclient11.2..

Comment: What's your OS/Linux and version?

Answer (score 1):

1: For your failed building, please give more details. Probably because you don't have the python development headers installed ("python-devel")

2: You need Oracle client installed as well, because cx_Oracle is just a linker between Python and the Oracle Client. Fast way is to get "Instant Client".

From the [cx-oracle's README](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/README.txt):

> Please note that an Oracle client (or server) installation is required in order to use cx_Oracle. If you do not require the tools that come with a full client installation, it is recommended to install the Instant Client which is far easier to install.

Comment: I don't know if there's "python-devel" for python3.x. IO can't fine one. I already have "Instant Client" like what I have said in item number1.